# How do I cast a json-like string to json object in alasql?

Tags: alasql

I have a json-like string:

```
'{"a":"b","c":"d"}'
```

I want to be able to query it in alasql like json, ie something like `column->a`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can convert json-like string to array of object and use `JSON.parse`. For example

```js
var data= '{"a":"b","c":"d"}'
var parseData = [JSON.parse(test)]
var response = alasql('SELECT * FROM ?',[parseData]);
console.log(response) // [ { a: 'b', c: 'd' } ]
```